# Actualizar json server en Angular luego de aplicar Drag & Drop a elementos en lista

Tags: angular, json, angular-material, server, drag-and-drop

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Angular donde se pueden agregar y eliminar tareas de una lista. estas se pueden agregar y borrar de un json, con json server. El problema que tengo es que por ultimo le apliqué Drag and Drop mediante Angular Materials a las tareas en lista para que el usuario las pueda acomodar en el orden que quiera. Todo funciona excepto que al final no he conseguido que la lista con el nuevo orden se actualice en el json, y claro, al refrescar la página las tareas vuelven al orden original.
¿Como puedo actualizar la lista en el json?

He intentado tanto con put, patch. Incluso intenté eliminar todas las tareas del json con delete en un bucle, para luego agregar la nueva lista item por item, pero me da error a medio camino de eliminado y se desconecta del servidor.

*Dejo el link del proyecto en mi GitHub:*
https://github.com/diegorus92/Task-list/tree/main/TaskList

**lista-tarea.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TAREAS } from '../../MockTareas';
import { ITarea } from 'src/app/Interfaces/ITarea';
import { TareaService } from "../../servicios/tarea.service";
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista-tareas',
  templateUrl: './lista-tareas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista-tareas.component.css']
})
export class ListaTareasComponent implements OnInit {

  tareas:ITarea[] = []; //Almacena las tareas recuperadas de la DB mediante el TareaService
  
  constructor(private servicioTareas:TareaService) { }
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.servicioTareas.getTareas()   
                                     
    .subscribe((tareas) => {  
      this.tareas = tareas;   
      this.servicioTareas.tareas = this.tareas; 
      this.servicioTareas.actualizarSubject();
      console.log("lista-tareas:",tareas);

      this.servicioTareas.ListaTarea$.subscribe(tareas => this.servicioTareas.tareas = tareas);
                                      
    })                                                                      
  }

  

  modificarRecordatorio(tarea:ITarea):void{
    tarea.recordatorio = !tarea.recordatorio;
    this.servicioTareas.modificarTarea(tarea).subscribe();
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<ITarea[]>){
    moveItemInArray(this.tareas, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    console.log("Ejecutado Drag&Drop: ",this.tareas);
    this.servicioTareas.alterarTareas(this.tareas).subscribe();
  }

}
```

**tarea.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ITarea } from '../Interfaces/ITarea';
import { TAREAS } from '../MockTareas';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParamsOptions } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, map } from 'rxjs';

const HttpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    contentType: 'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TareaService {


  tareas:ITarea[] = []; //almacenara las tarear recuperadas de la DB
  private ListaTareas = new BehaviorSubject<ITarea[]>([]); 
                                                          
  private apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/tareas";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


  get ListaTarea$():Observable<ITarea[]>{ 
    return this.ListaTareas.asObservable();
  }

  getTareas():Observable<ITarea[]> { //devuelve asincronicamente las tareas contenidas en la DB
    return this.http.get<ITarea[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }


  actualizarSubject():void{ 
    this.ListaTareas.next(this.tareas);
  }



  agregarTarea(tarea:ITarea):Observable<ITarea>{
                                                
    tarea.id! = this.generarId();
    this.tareas.push(tarea);
    this.ListaTareas.next(this.tareas);
    return this.http.post<ITarea>(this.apiUrl, tarea, HttpOptions);
  }

  

  generarId():number{
    return this.tareas.length > 0 ? Math.max(...this.tareas.map(tarea => tarea.id!)) +1 : 1;
  }

  buscarIndiceTarea(tarea:ITarea):number{                 
    return this.tareas.findIndex(obj => obj.id == tarea.id)
  }

  

  modificarTarea(tarea:ITarea):Observable<ITarea>{//Modifica de momento el estado de "recordatorio" de una tarea en la DB
    let url = `${this.apiUrl}/${tarea.id}`;
    return this.http.put<ITarea>(url, tarea, HttpOptions);
  }

  private removerTareaDeLista(tarea:ITarea):void{                    
    let indice:number = this.buscarIndiceTarea(tarea);
    if(indice > -1){
      this.tareas.splice(indice, 1);
    }
    else
      console.log("tarea no encontrada");
  }


  removerTarea(tarea:ITarea):Observable<ITarea>{
    this.removerTareaDeLista(tarea);
    let url = `${this.apiUrl}/${tarea.id}`;
    return this.http.delete<ITarea>(url);
  }

  alterarTareas(tareas:ITarea[]):Observable<ITarea[]>{
    let url = "http://localhost:3000/tareas";
    return this.http.put<ITarea[]>(url,tareas, HttpOptions);
  }

}
```

**db.json**

```
{
  "tareas": [
    {
      "descripcion": "Jugar al COD Mobile",
      "dia": "Ahora mismo papuh :V",
      "recordatorio": false,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "Hacer ejercicio físico",
      "dia": "Lunes 08 a las 16:30hs",
      "recordatorio": false,
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "Limpiar mi cuarto",
      "dia": "Domingo 07 a las 18:00hs",
      "recordatorio": true,
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "Crear base de datos para el proyecto",
      "dia": "Domingo 28, 22:00hs",
      "recordatorio": true,
      "id": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

en el componente lista-tareas.component.ts, al hacer el drag y soltar la tarea, se dispara la funcion "drop" y allí acceso a la lista modificada, y mediante la funcion "alterarTareas" en tarea.service.ts pretendo reemplazar la lista de tareas del db.json por la nueva con el orden alterado. Lo mas que pude conseguir fué mediante un post, sin embargo, lo que hace es duplicarme la lista en el json, manteniendo la original y debajo agregando la misma con el nuevo ordenamiento.

Muchas gracias de antemano
Saludos.

Comment: El problema parece que está en el backend, que en lugar de modificar los datos ya guardados, agrega los nuevos. Pero sin ver el código de ese punto final de tu API no puedo aportar nada más.

Comment: @PedroGonzález Hola Pedro. Aquí te dejo el link del proyecto en mi repositorio GitHub:
https://github.com/diegorus92/Task-list/tree/main/TaskList
Lo actualizaré en mi pregunta también. Muchas gracias

Comment: @PedroGonzález Muchisimas  gracias Pedro!. Explicaste perfectamente todo, no se te escapó nada y solucionó mi problema fácilmente.
Tendré en cuenta ver otras formas de abordar el tema como sugieres, pero de momento tu solución quedó de 10. 
Marcaré como resuelto y puntuaré tu respuesta(aunque por mi baja reputación no se mostrará). Saludos Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que el backend lo haces con json-server. Bien, habría varias formas de abordar este problema, pero una que se me ocurre es la de añadir a cada registro un campo, por ejemplo que se llame **orden** y que mantendría el orden dentro de la lista.

Habría que hacer algunos cambios en el código.

Modificar tu interface en el fichero **iTarea.ts** para que se añada este campo

```
export interface ITarea{
    id?: number;
    descripcion: string;
    dia: string;
    recordatorio: boolean;
    orden: number;
}
```

Al agregar una tarea (en el servicio), añade el orden. Para esto, puedes recorrer la lista de tareas y buscar el elemento que tenga el orden más alto y asignas a la nueva tarea el orden siguiente

```
agregarTarea(tarea:ITarea):Observable<ITarea>{//agrega la nueva tarea en la lista tareas de la clase
                                                //Agrega la tarea nueva a la ListaTareas
                                                //Agrega la tarea nueva a la DB
    // La añadimos al final, así que busco el valor de orden más alto y le sumo uno
    var orden = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<this.tareas.length; i++)
      if(this.tareas[i].orden > orden)
        orden = this.tareas[i].orden;
    // Le asigno el nuevo valor de orden a la taréa que voy a insertar
    tarea.orden = orden + 1;

    tarea.id! = this.generarId();
    this.tareas.push(tarea);
    this.ListaTareas.next(this.tareas);
    return this.http.post<ITarea>(this.apiUrl, tarea, HttpOptions);
  }
```

Cuando leas las tareas (en lista-tareas.component.ts), ordena la lista por su campo **orden**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.getTareas();

    this.servicioTareas.getTareas()   //Se suscribe al obserbavle getTareas() que recupera asincronicamente
                                      //las tareas de la DB
    .subscribe((tareas) => {  //Dentro del subscribe, recupera las tareas de la DB y:
      // Ordeno la lista de tareas recibidas en función de su campo "orden"
      tareas.sort( (a:ITarea, b:ITarea) => {
        if(a.orden > b.orden) return 1;
        if(a.orden < b.orden) return -1;
        return 0;
      });

      this.tareas = tareas;   //-las almacena en la lista tareas de esta clase...
      this.servicioTareas.tareas = this.tareas; //-copia la lista tareas de esta clase a la lista tareas de la del servicio...
      this.servicioTareas.actualizarSubject();//-ejectuta la funcion del servicio que actualiza la ListaTareas del mismo con el contenido de su lista tareas del mismo cargada en la linea anterior...
      console.log("lista-tareas:",tareas);

      this.servicioTareas.ListaTarea$.subscribe(tareas => this.servicioTareas.tareas = tareas);//-finalmente nos subscribimos a ListaTarea$ que nos actualiza asincronicamente los cambios en el listado de tareas
                                      //Por si a caso en el subscribe volvemos a copiar las tareas de la lista tareas de esta clase a la lista tareas del servicio
    })
  }
```

Por último, al hacer el drop, renumera el orden de las tareas con el nuevo orden y modifica los registros

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<ITarea[]>){

    moveItemInArray(this.tareas, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    console.log("Ejecutado Drag&Drop: ",this.tareas);

    // Renumero el orden
    for(var i=0; i<this.tareas.length; i++){
      this.tareas[i].orden = i;
      this.servicioTareas.modificarTarea(this.tareas[i]).subscribe();
    }
  }
```

Recuerda actualizar el json que ya tienes para añadir a mano el campo orden, asignándole un valor secuencial a cada registro.

También puedes actualizar tu fichero MockTareas.ts y en tareas.componen.ts actualiza el @input

```
@Input() tarea:ITarea = {
    descripcion:"",
    dia:"",
    recordatorio: false,
    orden: 0
  };
```

Espero que no se me quede nada y, como te digo, no es la única forma de hacerlo, te invito a que investigues otras alternativas.